# Communities-Setting

Tags: salesforce-classic

In Sharing set for communities nothing is coming for available profile. PFA snapshot.Can anybody please let me know how to add profile in available profiles.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sharing sets are available only for licenses mentioned below. Its GA for customer and partner community and beta in other other ones

[image]
can you check if you have any other profiles cloned from these profiles created from the license mentioned above.

Comment: Yes its available for above license I agree but my question is, I have another sandbox which is just the replica of this sandbox but it has some other profiles coming under Available profile. So,for this sandbox those profiles should also come under available Profile.Is there some settings by which we can make them available in available profile?Yes We have Partner Community license profile as well but its not coming in available Profile.

Comment: Is that profile available in the sandbox that you are testing and is there already a sharing set configured for this profile. you can see that below in the list view

Comment: Yes that profile is available in the sandbox and there is already a sharing set but it is not using that profile.That Profile is not present under Available Profiles even for that Sharing set.